# Передвижение Object3D() в Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Есть 3D объект, состоящий из нескольких мешей, по отдельности каждый меш двигается плавно (использую translateX), но как только начинаю передвигать 3D объект, он передвигается рывками, при этом копируя предыдущую версию. Как исправить? Возможно нужно постоянно обновлять сцену

Comment: да, нужно обновлять сцену. покажите код, который вы написали, посмотреть, что там не так

Comment: //Передвижение объекта
function Keyboard(){
    
    if(event.keyCode == 87){
     object3d.mesh.translateX(10);

    }
//Сцена 
function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    createObject();
           renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
    };

Comment: полный код покажите ?

Comment: вызов `createObject();` в функции `render()`??